# uncaught typeerror read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, html

```
                            var Z;
                            var E;
                             
              Z=document.getElementById("X").value;
              E=document.getElementById("Y").value;
```

I don't know why but I couldn't solve this problem
If you run the codes, the following error appears in the console uncaught typeerror read properties of null (reading 'value')

Comment: Do you have elements with those ids in your HTML, and are you calling your script after the DOM has loaded? Are those elements `input` elements? Do they have values when the page is loaded?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would double-check that the output of `document.getElementById("X")` and `document.getElementById("Y")` is what you expected. In case there's a mismatch in the ids (*typos can happen*), or for some other reason the `getElementById` can't lookup the DOM element, you'll get `null` as result.

Comment: How do you think the problem is solved? I double checked and even got some code from the internet to make sure there are no typos.